# Error in installing .net framework 3.5 sp1 on windows 7

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008

I am having windows 7 (64 bit) Operating system. I have installed vs 2008 and sql 2005 on my machine. I want to install sql server 2008. When I trying to install SQL 2008, it fail. So I downloaded 3.5 sp1 and try to install it. But installation fail. 
It gives error Error occur during installation. I unchecked the check-box of framework 3.5 by going in control panel(Windows feature turn on and off)but no luck.

Can anybody tell me what is solution of this?

Comment: did you simply perform a normal install, or did you right-click and install as Administrator?

Comment: and it gave you not other information as to why it failed??

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/netfxsetup/thread/7767ef34-2dd0-4fe9-9e59-cbdfd0de8476

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsnetsetup/archive/2012/10/07/installation-of-net-framework-3-5-sp1-fails-due-to-an-existing-net-4-0-mscoree-dll.aspx

Comment: this one might be your best bet: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/da-DK/netfxsetup/thread/13b79cd2-788f-4d99-b21a-2baf02ffea13